# IdMappedPortTCP - No Events

Tags: delphi, proxy, indy

I have a the indy component:

```
IdMappedPortTCP1: TIdMappedPortTCP;
```

and the following initialization:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  IdMappedPortTCP1.MappedHost := '189.200.10.71';
  IdMappedPortTCP1.MappedPort := 5300;
  IdMappedPortTCP1.Active := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AContext.Data.ToString);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('------');
end;

procedure TForm1.IdMappedPortTCP1OutboundData(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AContext.Data.ToString);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('+++++++'); //
end;
```

My other application connects to 189.200.10.71:5300 but the component is not firing...

Where is my fault?

Using XE3 with the include indy components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MappedHost/MappedPort` properties tell `TIdMappedPortTCP` where it connects to once a client has connected to it.  You are telling `TIdMappedPortTCP` to connect to `189.200.10.71:5300`.  If your other app is also connecting to `189.200.10.71:5300` then it is bypassing `TIdMappedPortTCP` completely.  That explains why the events are not firing (BTW, `TIdMappedPortTCP` is a multi-threaded components but your event handlers are not thread-safe).

To go through `TIdMappedPortTCP`, the client needs to connect to an IP/Port that the `TIdMappedPortTCP.Bindings` collection is listening on, not the IP/Port assigned to the `MappedHost/MappedPort` properties.

Comment: Thank you Remy... Fault in my brain.exe i think... so i need set default host/port to the one where my application will connect to (like 127.0.0.1:1000) right?

Comment: If you configured `TIdMappedPortTCP` to listen for clients on 127.0.0.1 on port 1000, then yes.

Comment: Hmmm... tried it.. but will lead me to the following problem... I can't chang the destination IP address of the other application. it uses IP's directely so a manipulation of hosts wouldn't help there...

Comment: Then you are out of luck if you can't change the IP/Port that the app connects to. It doesn't have its own configuration for that? I find it unlikely that the IP would be hard-coded in the app's code, so it has to be getting it from somewhere.

Comment: The first IP is in a config file, but the programm receives it's final ip's after conencting to the first one....

Comment: In that case, you will have to change the first IP to point at one `TIdMappedPortTCP` instance, having it analyze data as it is being exchanged, dynamically altering the other IPs as needed to point at another `TIdMappedPortTCP` instance. Since you will know the original IPs, you can assign them to that instance's `MappedHost` property.